# How to reference a json array element by name using Python?

Tags: python, arrays, json

In this json array:

```
json_string=[{"Id": "report","Value": "3001"},{"Id": "user","Value": "user123"}]
```

How can I get back *user123* if I pass in *user*

When I try to do this:

```
content = json.loads(json_string) 
content['user']
```

I get an error that says you have to use integer to reference an element.

I am brand new to Python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`content` is a list so you should get the element by index first:

```
>>> content[1]['Value']
'user123'

>>> for d in content:
...     if 'user' in d.values():
...         print d['Value']
'user123'
```

Assuming `user` is always mapped to `Id`:

```
>>> for d in content:
...     if d['Id'] == 'user':
...         print d['Value']
```

One liner:

```
 >>> [d['Value'] for d in content if d['Id'] == 'user'][0]
 'user123'
```

Comment: Or more generally, `[ x for x in content where x['Id'] == "user"][0]["Value"]`

Comment: Thank you! There's no way of saying, give me the value where the element Id is User? Without having to reference the index? I know I can loop over it, but just thought it could be done in one line.

Comment: @chepner, Yes!! that's it. Thank you!

Comment: I think it is, anyway. I've edited my comment several times so far :)

Comment: @chepner I assumed 'user' may not have to be mapped to `Id` always.

Comment: It looks like the json is a list of key/value pairs. If that's consistently true and if you're going to be making multiple lookups into a single json blob, you might benefit from converting it into a dict - something like `content = dict((pair['Id'], pair['Value']) for pair in json.loads(json_string))`. Then `content['user']` would work. But if you only need to look up one value the one liner above is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to focus on the first occurrence of an element in the list with a given field (e.g. 'Id') with a certain value (e.g. 'user'):

```
def look_for(string, field, val):
    return next((el['Value'] for el in string if el[field] == val))

json_string = [{"Id": "report","Value": "3001"}, {"Id": "user","Value": "user123"}]
found_val = look_for(json_string, 'Id', 'user')
```

produces

```
'user123'
```

Obviously, also the output field can become a parameter instead of being hardcoded to `Value`